# Angular "@ngx-translate/core" library TranslateModule is declared in the root but not overrided in the Child module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internationalization, ngx-translate

I'm using "@ngx-translate/core" library to apply internationalization, I've created a helper service for it and configured it in all my modules, I also installed "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader", To allow reading more than one key and then fetching it's values from english or french files depending on the language needed.
My problem is that the import in my app module is not overrided in the shild module, This is my code.

This is my Child module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CheckinCkeckoutRackRoutingModule } from './checkin-ckeckout-rack-routing.module';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { LoadRackComponent } from './load-rack/load-rack.component';
import { RackInfoComponent } from './rack-info/rack-info.component';
import { RackActionComponent } from './rack-action/rack-action.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RackService } from '../../setup/manage-rack/service/rack.service';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { RacktransactionService } from '../service/racktransaction.service';
import { ManagestorageService } from '../../setup/manage-storage/services/managestorage.service';
import { SamplestoragelogserviceService } from '../../sample-storage-log/services/samplestoragelogservice.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SearchCriteriaService } from '../service/searchcriteriadata.service';
import { HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpLoaderFactory } from '@/shared/helpers/helper-transalation.service';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [IndexComponent, LoadRackComponent, RackInfoComponent, RackActionComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    CheckinCkeckoutRackRoutingModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (httpBackend: HttpBackend) => HttpLoaderFactory(httpBackend, 'sample-storage'), 
        deps: [HttpBackend]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    RackService,
    RacktransactionService,
    ManagestorageService,
    SamplestoragelogserviceService,
    RackService,
    SearchCriteriaService,  
  ],
})
export class CheckinCkeckoutRackModule { }
```

And this is my App module:

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MegaMenuModule } from 'primeng/megamenu';
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';
import { MenubarModule } from 'primeng/menubar';
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/dropdown';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { MessagesModule } from 'primeng/messages';
import { MessageModule } from 'primeng/message';
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';
import { MenuModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-menu';
import { ToastyModule, ToastyService } from 'ng2-toasty';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from '@material-controls-module/angular-material.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import 'hammerjs';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { TreeViewModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-treeview';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ConfigService } from '@core-services/config.service';
import { getBaseUrl } from '@shared-helpers/helper-url';
import { LayoutModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from '@shared-components/base-component/confirmDialog/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { InterceptorsList } from './core/interceptor/Interceptors';
import { LoaderServiceModule } from './core/layout/loader/loader-service.module';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { RegistrationService } from './modules/registration/Services/registration.service';
import { ToolsModule } from './modules/tools/tools.module';
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
import { PatientLastVisitComponent } from './modules/registration/component/Dialogs/patient-last-visit/patient-last-visit.component';
import { DynamicFileUploadComponent } from './dynamic-control-module/controls/dynamic-file-upload/dynamic-file-upload.component';
import { SharedFileUploadComponent } from './dynamic-control-module/controls/shared-file-upload/shared-file-upload.component';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { DyanmicRegFormService } from './modules/registration/Services/DynamicRegisterationServices/reg-dynamic-form.service';
import { LoyaltyModule } from './modules/loyalty/loyalty.module';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpLoaderFactory } from './shared/helpers/helper-transalation.service';
import { KendoDatepickerComponent } from './shared/components/kendo-datepicker/kendo-datepicker.component';
import { KendoTimepickerComponent } from './shared/components/kendo-timepicker/kendo-timepicker.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ConfirmDialogComponent,
        PatientLastVisitComponent,
        DynamicFileUploadComponent,
        SharedFileUploadComponent

    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MegaMenuModule,
        ButtonsModule,
        MenubarModule,
        DropdownModule,
        ToastyModule,
        MessagesModule,
        MessageModule,
        ToastModule,
        MenuModule,
        GridModule,
        AngularMaterialModule,
        TreeViewModule,
        DropDownsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        LayoutModule,
        ToolsModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        LoaderServiceModule,
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        ToastyModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (httpBackend: HttpBackend) => HttpLoaderFactory(httpBackend, 'app'),
                deps: [HttpBackend]
            }
        }),
        LoyaltyModule
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: setConfig,
            multi: true,
            deps: [HttpClient, ConfigService]
        },
        DatePipe,
        MessageService,
        ToastyService,
        Title,
        InterceptorsList,
        RegistrationService,
        DyanmicRegFormService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function setConfig(http: HttpClient, configService: ConfigService) {
    return async () => {
        const resp = await http.get(getBaseUrl() + 'config.json').toPromise();
        configService.configuration = <any>resp;
    };
}
```

And This is my Translation helper service:

```
import { HttpBackend } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { MultiTranslateHttpLoader } from "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TranslationHelperService {
    /**
     *
     */
    constructor(private readonly translate: TranslateService) {
        this.translate.use('en');

    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param resourceKey 
     * @param resourceKeyParamters 
     * @returns Promise<string>
     */
   public async getTransaltedMsg(resourceKey: any, resourceKeyParamters: any = null):Promise<string> {
        if (!resourceKeyParamters) {
            return await this.translate.get(resourceKey).toPromise();
        } else {
            return await this.translate.get(resourceKey, resourceKeyParamters).toPromise();
        }
    }
}
 /**
  * 
  * @param _httpBackend 
  * @param moduleName 
  * @returns 
  */
export function HttpLoaderFactory(_httpBackend: HttpBackend, moduleName: string) {
    return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(_httpBackend, [
      {prefix: './assets/i18n/shared/', suffix: '.json'},
      {prefix: `./assets/i18n/${moduleName}/`}
    ]);
}
```

The import: TranslateModule is not overrided in the child module and always sends the string: 'app' not 'sample-storage', Need to know the reason and how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Please **create translation files** in *src/assets/i18n* directory.

Then create the json files for the different languages you want to use in your app. Here is the directory example -

This is how you can write your json files.

// en.json

```
{
  "signin": "Please enter your credentials.",
  "signup": "Please create a new account"
}
```

// es.json

```
{
  "signin": "Por favor, ingresa tus credenciales.",
  "signup": "Por favor, crea una nueva cuenta."
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this already, if I change the string sent from the app module from 'app' to 'sample-storage ' for example it will work for sample-storage module which is a child of the app module.
So, what we conclude is that whatever we send from the app module is not changed in the child modules